# IllegalMonitorStateException injava

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi i am trying to make Multiplayer game using Java socket programming.My server is using Multithreading enviornment.The problem is that , i want when both player will connect to the server then they can proceed forword other wise not...For this reason i have use loop for run for 2 times and accepts connectons from the both clients.and in loop i have use thread object and call its wait method ..When the loop is finish i have call obj.notifyALl method so that the current thread and previous threed shoudl awake and they will start work But i  am getting this exception ...Any ideas or suggestion are welcome.....

Comment: Please post some code and show us the stack trace. This will make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 3):

In short: you are waiting or notifying on an object you haven't synchronized.

From [Object.wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29)

> The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.
>
> As in the one argument version, interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible, and this method should always be used in a loop:

```
 synchronized (obj) {
     while (<condition does not hold>)
         obj.wait();
     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
 }
```

> IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor.

IMHO Its likely you should be using the [concurrency library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) instead of wait/notify.

Answer (score 0):

Threads should call `obj.wait()` in order `obj.notifyAll()` to work. And it should be called from `synchronized` block.

```
synchronized (obj) {
   //While condition is not true wait
}
```

[Javadoc # IllegalMonitorStateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.